# Multi-threaded code not working as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading

As I am very new to the concept of Multi-Threading, I'm trying to keep things very simple. The complete program I have written below in **Visual Studio 2019** was an attempt to compare the performance of a single thread vs 3 threads running simultaneously. Each thread has its own data to work on so I have assumed there is no need for data protection from the other threads.

The algorithm simply creates the first 64 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence, and is recreated millions of times. The algorithm doesn't really have a practical use. It was just created to waste CPU time.

On a modern day laptop running at 2 GHz, a **single thread** takes about **7.6 seconds** to complete.
Unfortunately with **3 threads**, most times it will take around **7 seconds** to complete. This is marginally better than a single thread!
However occasionally **3 threads** will take about **2.54 seconds** to complete. This last time is a little over 1/3 the time of a single thread and is what I expected to occur most of the time.

I'm not sure what's going on here. But it does appear to be a stall of some sort or a synchronisation issue. Any help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define ITERATIONS 10000000

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void WasteTime(__int64 fib[], int start, int end)
{
    int i;
    
    for (i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        // Initialise the sequence
        fib[0] = 1;
        fib[1] = 1;
        
        // Create Fibonacci sequence
        for (int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, f3 = 2; f1 < 62; f1++, f2++, f3++)
        {
            fib[f3] = fib[f1] + fib[f2];
        }

        // Display iteration count
        if (i % 0x1000000 == 0)
            printf("%10u\n", i);
    }
    // Display final iteration count for thread
    printf("%10u\n", i);
}

void WasteTimeUsingThreads(__int64 fib1[], __int64 fib2[], __int64 fib3[])
{
    thread t1(WasteTime, fib1,               0, 10 * ITERATIONS);
    thread t2(WasteTime, fib2, 10 * ITERATIONS, 20 * ITERATIONS);
    thread t3(WasteTime, fib3, 20 * ITERATIONS, 30 * ITERATIONS);

    // Before the main thread continues running, wait for all threads to finish.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}

int main()
{
    __int64 fib1[64], fib2[64], fib3[64];

    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    WasteTime(fib1, 0, 30 * ITERATIONS);
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    cout << "Time for normal way is: " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count() << endl;

    start = steady_clock::now();
    WasteTimeUsingThreads(fib1, fib2, fib3);
    end = steady_clock::now();
    cout << "Time for multithreaded way is: " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count() << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: creating threads is expensive. try creating the threads before you measure. you can use srd::async with deferred|async policy. this will use threads from a thread pool on msvc

Comment: @Raildex With the total time>1 seconds and only 3 threads, I think the thread creation time is insignificant.

Comment: I've used larger sets of iterations, 30 seconds for single thread. But still 3 threads can take as long as 20 to 30 seconds and occasionally a little over 10 seconds (which is what I was aiming for).

Comment: @SolomonSlow. The CPU in question is an i5 1035G4 (@ 2.0 GHz). So 4 cores 8 threads. The code above was compiled in a VS2019 project and executed many times. Most of the time the single thread completed in 7.6 to 7.8 seconds. And most of the time the 3 threads completed in the range of 6 to 8 seconds averaging around 7 or so. But occasionally the 3 threads would complete in a little over 2.5 seconds. There's no consistency! If a single thread is consistent at completing a task in 7.5 seconds, then spreading the task over 3 threads should yield a result closer to 2.5 seconds. But this isn't so.

Comment: @SolomonSlow. A millisecond timer is used to get the difference in times, just before and after execution of the WasteTime function.

Comment: Deleting my original comment, because I made it without reading your `main()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `fib1`, `fib2`, `fib3` arrays are small, and probably share the same [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) line on a modern processor (e.g. some Intel or AMD in 64 bits mode, designed after 2015). So you could have contentions. Read about [cache coherency protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherency_protocols_(examples)).

Did you try with arrays larger than the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) size (usually 4Kbytes at least on many processors)?

Be sure to enable optimizations in your compiler. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) `g++ -O2` at least.

And you could use profiling utilities, like Linux [oprofile(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/oprofile.1.html)

On my Linux [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) 21 desktop (AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2970WX), I use (with `<stdint.h>` header) `#define ITERATIONS 20000000` and `int64_t fib1[4096], fib2[4096], fib3[4096];` as local variables, and compiled with `/usr/bin/g++-10 -std=c++11 -O2` your `john.cc` file. Output has:

```
Time for normal way is: 47255
Time for multithreaded way is: 16074
```

I tried also to compile with `/usr/bin/g++-11 -std=c++11 -O3 john.cc -o john -lstdc++ -lpthread` and the performance are even better:

```
Time for normal way is: 11714
Time for multithreaded way is: 3989
```

Same code with

```
int64_t fib1[128], fib2[128], fib3[128];
```

compiled using `/usr/bin/g++-11 -std=c++11 -O1 john.cc -o john -lstdc++ -lpthread` gives

```
Time for normal way is: 51973
Time for multithreaded way is: 17678
```

which is consistent with my intuitions.

Comment: Basile is referring to the concept of "cache coherency".

Comment: Thanks to whoever for formatting improvement! I'm still new here. only my 3rd question. I'll look into those suggestions soon. But I'm still curious why occasionally I get the almost 3 fold improvement without consistency.

Comment: You may want to read a book about processor architecture. Processors are so complex today that predicting their timing behavior is nearly impossible, and compilers are complex software too

Comment: You could read *Embedded Computing* (ISBN 1-55860-766-8) or a newer book, and of course the [*Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. As you outlined at the beginning of your answer, the array sizes were too small. When I changed them to 128, everytime I ran the code, I got a perfomance increase of almost 3 to 1! So if your data sets are too small, it can severely impact the perfomance of multithreaded algorithms.